# Ask for input and print that location in an array

Tags: c#

Hoping someone can help.  I am teaching myself C# and one of the challenges in this chapter has tasked me with storing the number of days in each month in an array which I called daysInMonth.  When the program starts, I am to ask for a user to input a number between 1 and 12 and then spit out the number of days in the month that corresponds with that number.

I have searched for this but am coming up with nothing.  Most examples are related to matching/finding an int or string with something in the array which isn't what I want.  I want something so that if the user enters the number 5, the program will print out whatever is in the 5th whatever in the array.  I know this is pretty easy but I think that my searching is coming up with nothing because I don't know the correct term to search for.  Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Thanks to MAV I got it working.  Posting full code of the program.

```
        int[] daysInMonth = new int[12] { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
        string[] monthNames = new string[12] { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
        int myChoice;

        Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");

        myChoice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (myChoice < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the number {0} is too low.  Please select a number between 1 and 12.", myChoice);
            Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
            myChoice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        else if (myChoice > 12)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the number {0} is too high.  Please select a number between 1 and 12.", myChoice);
            Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
            myChoice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        int i = daysInMonth[myChoice - 1];
        string m = monthNames[myChoice - 1];

        Console.WriteLine("Thank you.  You entered the number {0}.", myChoice);
        Console.WriteLine("That number corresponds with the month of {0}.", m);
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} days in this month.", i);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: please provide the code you have, then someone might be able to advise how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to learn C# I am not going to give you what I believe is the answer. Instead I will try to give you knowledge about how to use arrays, since that seems to be your problem.

You can declare arrays like this:

```
 int[] intArray = {1, 2, 3};      //This array contains 1, 2 and 3
 int[] intArray2 = new int[12];   //This array have 12 spots you can fill with values
 intArray2[2] = 42;               //element 2 in intArray2 now contains the value 42
```

To access an element in an array, you can do this:

```
int i = intArray2[2];             //Integer i now contains the value 42.
```

For more information about arrays and how to use them I can recommend reading this tutorial: [Arrays Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: That was really good, thank you so much.  That gave me enough info to figure it out for myself.  I did appreciate that too.  You get that warm fuzzy feeling when you get it to work yourself.  :)